# php index.php, add to cart issue

Tags: php, apache

I am having trouble executing this code in my index.php.

It says 'CartAction not set'

I need your help php gurus. I can display any files you need to fix this error.

Here is the code:

```
// Handle AJAX requests
if (isset ($_GET['AjaxRequest']))
{
// Headers are sent to prevent browsers from caching
header('Expires: Fri, 25 Dec 1980 00:00:00 GMT'); // Time in the past
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Content-Type: text/html');

  if (isset ($_GET['CartAction']))
  {
    $cart_action = $_GET['CartAction'];

    if ($cart_action == ADD_PRODUCT)
    {
      require_once 'C:/vhosts/phpcs5/presentation/' . 'cart_details.php';

      $cart_details = new CartDetails();
      $cart_details->init();

      $application->display('cart_summary.tpl');
    }
    else
    {
      $application->display('cart_details.tpl');
    }
  }
  else
    trigger_error('CartAction not set', E_USER_ERROR);
}
else
{
  // Display the page
  $application->display('store_front.tpl');
}
```

Comment: Well it says it right there, it's missing an action from the URL - what's the current URL you're sending to Cart API?

Comment: just check your get array by print_r($_GET) ; also remove all code and test just with an echo "success"

Comment: my .htaccess file includes # Rewrite cart details pages
RewriteRule ^cart-details/?$ index.php?CartAction [L]

Comment: @user2950085 You wouldn't do this via .htaccess, it's all about what you're sending as an URL. The outcome of the script is dependant on what you send, as it's based on MVC Structure - here's an fictional example (that *won't* work, `?cartaction=add&productsku=231&qty=3`) which will add 3 of product 231.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your code is expecting a parameter named 'CartAction' in the url

Example:

```
www.yoursite.com/?CartAction=ADD_PRODUCT
```

The GET method sends the encoded user information appended to the page request. The page and the encoded information are separated by the ? character. [Source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm)

You check `if $_GET['CartAction']` has a value ( from the above url this [superglobal variable](http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.superglobals.php) has the value 'ADD_PRODUCT' )

Answer (score 0):

What @Mackiee (in comments) and your error message are both telling you is that the problem is that there is a query parameter missing. The URL that calls this needs to include either `?CartAction=ADD_PRODUCT` or `&CartAction=ADD_PRODUCT`